# How to use a GitHub project in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, github

I know there are already similar question but I still could not find a way to do this. I want to use [this](https://github.com/gitgrimbo/android-sliding-menu-demo) github project in a new android app. Could anyone elaborate how to do that ?

Comment: First you need to clone the project to your desired folder as follows

    "git clone https://github.com/gitgrimbo/android-sliding-menu-demo.git"

 A `clone` is a copy of a repository that lives on your computer instead of on a website's server somewhere, or the act of making that copy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easy.
For example, you want to add the library which is given below.

1)just take compile link  -->   `compile 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.2'`

2)add it in app level gradle

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.2'
}
```

3)sync project
Now u can use easily this github library.

EDIT:

In the latest version of Android Studio `implementation` must be used instead of `compile`

So,

`compile 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.2'`

becomes,

`implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.2'`

Answer (score 1):

First,you need to download the project .Then,you should follow the steps below,in you project,chose Android studio File->new->import module.Find the path of the project which was downloaded just now into Source directory.The last step ,into project structure select dependencies, chose Module dependency,click Ok.So,you can use the github project in you new android app.Sorry，my english is very pool ,hope that can help you.